# Output shows "ResultSet" instead of value in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I'm writing a Spark streaming job and want to find out what's in my `List`, `ArrayList`, or what my return integers are.

This part of my code is supposed to print an integer result of a calculation:

```
println(math.floor(insights2.getTweetsFromCassandra(param1, pram2)).toInt)
```

However, when I run the streaming job, I get this output:

> ResultSet[ exhausted: false, Columns[target(varchar)]]

How can I print out actual values instead, whether an integer or list?

Comment: Can you show the snippet of the code and the exception in bit detail please?

Comment: Ah my bad, here it is:

println(math.floor(insights2.getTweetsFromCassandra(param1, pram2)).toInt)

I'm expecting the return to be an integer but I get the line above.

Comment: I edited your question and title a bit, and added that code into it. I hope I didn't misunderstand what you were asking—if so, just use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30745121/edit) link below your question to fix or improve it. I wonder if you could add something to it to be clearer about which `List`s you're hoping to print?